# Insert DataTable into nested TreeView c#

Tags: c#, treeview

I got a database like

```
CID     | CName   | CParent 
--------+---------+---------
 1      | A       |  0
 2      | b       |  1
 3      | c       |  1  
 4      | d       |  1   
 5      | e       |  2
 6      | f       |  3
 7      | g       |  6  
 8      | h       |  2 
 9      | i       |  8
```

I want to represent this data into a nested treeview connecting each entity to its father which is the CParent.

What is the best way to get this treeview and how?

Comment: It's a **treeview** (not a *treeviwe*)

Comment: Are you using winforms, mvc or asp.net?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco am using winform